# Strategies for optimizing OpenGL-based animated/zoomable 2D UI rendering

Tags: opengl-es, 2d, gpu, mipmaps

I've built a scene graph based rendering system for my app's UI (http://audulus.com if you're curious). The app's UI is procedural, and a lot of it is animated. There are few pre-rendered images.

Currently, it caches unchanging groups of drawables in mipmapped textures. I use mipmaps because the UI is zoomable. Overall, this has been a big performance win, but there are several downsides:

1. Building the mipmaps (via glGenerateMipmap) takes time, reducing the frame rate when one part of the UI goes from animated to static.
2. Visual differences between the texture-cached geometry and not, causing slight flickering. (Might be able to get around this by being more clever with my path rendering code, but it seems hard)
3. Memory usage for all the textures (I could dump the offscreen textures, but that exacerbates problem 1)

A couple alternative approaches I've thought of:

1. Instead of texture caching, coalesce static paths into bigger paths. My paths are already VBO/VAO-based, but this could reduce the number of GL calls. (When turning off texture caching, my performance is mainly CPU-bound). Big win on memory usage. The primary problems with this approach are: complicating my path rendering shader (since it must handle paths with different attributes within one call to glDrawArrays), not handling the caching of other primitives (such as text), and more of a burden on the GPU than simply rendering a texture.
2. Still use textures, but avoid mip-mapping. As the UI is zoomed, textures could be resized (though this might have to be deferred since re-rendering the whole UI during zooming is too expensive). Delete textures for offscreen geometry. Downside of course is poor texture magnification/minification during UI zooming.

**UPDATE**

I tried (2). Resizing the textures is quite slow, so I prevent the UI from resizing them during zoom. This works reasonably well, but the magnification looks terrible when zooming starting small:

[image: Poor magnification]

Note that some of the modules aren't texture cached because they are tagged as animating.

**UPDATE 2**

I'm beginning to work on approach 1, so I deactivated the texture caching.

Though I'm CPU bound, practically all my GPU-side load comes from my path anti-aliasing fragment shader. Here's what performance looks like with it on:

[image: Performance with Path-AA shader active]

And with it off:

[image: Performance with Path-AA shader deactivated]

So further optimization of that will be a big win on the GPU side. I tried ditching it and going with 4x supersampling, but that looks like garbage, reminding me why I spent considerable time working on the path rendering shader.

Comment: Is your path rendering based on drawing GL_LINEs? Do you simplify geometry when you zoom out - as in, you do have LOD for your objects?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The paths are all using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. I don't have any LOD. As a test, I tried reducing the path tessellation detail, and it did reduce the GPU rendering time somewhat, but without the texture caching I'm CPU-bound. So dynamic LOD would be a good thing to implement once I've lowered the CPU-side burden a bit :-)

Comment: What exactly is your CPU-side burden? Is it transforming these vertices? Or is it just sending them per-frame to the GPU?

Comment: The vertices are stored in VBOs (in coordinates local to their drawable) and transformed in the vertex shader. I think my CPU side burden is largely due to the sheer number of OpenGL calls (780 calls to glDrawArrays per frame in the document pictured above), but potentially I'm doing something wrong that requires the CPU to wait for the GPU (still investigating that). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Do you issue many glDrawArrays call against one VBO or do you have many VBOs? Also are you calling glFlush/glFinish anywhere before you finish your sequence of glDrawArrays calls?

Comment: Each path has a separate VBO :-\. Do you think I'd get a performance boost by consolidating the VBOs, even if I still have to call glDrawArrays once for each path (I have to change uniforms for transform, path thickness, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Approach (1) is a big win. It has essentially the same performance as texture caching, but without any visual artifacts or much memory usage.

[image]